# SQL/ACCESS one-sided one-to-one relationship data integrity

Tags: sql, ms-access, one-to-one, data-integrity

I have a DB that contains two tables for now:

- **"Users":** includes data loaded from a CSV.
- **"Accounts":** Account opened for a certain user.

Both tables have numeric ID field ("UserID", "AccountID"), as the "Accounts" table also has a field called "UserID" for linking these two tables together.

I wish to connect these two tables to make sure that new records in "Accounts" can be added only if they have a matching inserted UserID that is found in the "Users" table. It sounded to me at first like a connection of one-to-one. However, while there can't be an account with a user that is not in the "Users" table, most of the records in "Users" still don't have an account in the "Accounts" table.

Is there any way to enforce data integrity about this relationship in ACCESS/SQL?

Comment: Have you googled MS Access foreign key?

Comment: Yes, can set relationship to enforce relational integrity so records in Accounts must have parent record in Users. However, to prevent multiple Accounts for a user, have to set the UserID 'foreign key' in Accounts as a primary key. Then don't have AccountID in Users. Why is this not one table?

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can by using foreignKeys. After you create the table Users with UserID as PrimaryKey, when you create the table Accounts with AccountsID as primaryKey you have to add UserID as a foreignKey and with a reference to UserId from Users table

```
  FOREIGN KEY (userID) REFERENCES Users(UserID)
```

Comment: Thank you for your comment. If I understood correctly - this foreign key makes sure that I  can't add an account with an invalid UserID. However, since both fields are indexed with no duplicates, I can't seem to make it work other than one-to-one, which fails again.
I want to allow the option to link between the tables, but also to make sure that there is no more than one UsedID or AccountID anywhere.

Comment: Why does one-to-one fail? Seems that's what you want. Set both UserID fields as primary key - that is one-to-one relationship. Then set UserID and AccountID in Accounts as compound index to prevent duplicate pairs. And AccountID should not be in Users. Preventing a duplicate account number will likely require some code to validate. Even if this were one table (why is it not?) would likely need some validation code.

Comment: @user8211163 Ok i made you a database with an example witch you can use https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1hGBIlzHfdz4Wk43cDExcbZfaZdyzNx7M?usp=sharing here is the download link. From this example i created two tables Users with userID as PrimaryKey and Accounts with accountID as PrimaryKey plus i added a variable called userID in Accounts witch will be my foreignKey not a primaryKey here in Accounts. Finnaly i made a relation between Users(userID) and Accounts(userID).